# Can I set a variable for the offset value?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to get a variable as the offset value but am getting an error back, any help?
Thanks

```
set offset_number = (select to_number(datediff(second,current_timestamp(),min("created_at"))*-1) from "PRESENTATION"."DWH"."TABLE");
-- 1607610

select $offset_number;
-- 1607610

select * from "STAGING"."DWH_STAGING"."S_TRADES" at(offset => $trade_date);
-- SQL compilation error: Invalid data type [$offset_number] in AT(OFFSET => $offset_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a copy/paste error:  `at(offset => $trade_date)` 
when your error message references `$offset_number`.

What if you explicitly cast offset_number as an integer?

```
set offset_number = (
 select to_number(datediff(second,current_timestamp(),min("created_at"))*-1)  
   from "PRESENTATION"."DWH"."TABLE")::integer;
```

or

```
select * from "STAGING"."DWH_STAGING"."S_TRADES"   
at(offset => $offset_number::integer);
```

-Paul-